# Determining the different spectra of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

So my question is how to exactly determine the different types of spectra (regular / continuous / point / resiudal) of an operator.
To use as an illustrative example, we consider the linear operator $A: l_2(\mathbb{N}) \to l_2(\mathbb{N})$ given by
$$
Ax:= \bigg ( \big( \frac{1}{n}+ \frac{4i}{n^2})x_n \big ) \bigg )_{n \in \mathbb{N}}
$$
So, I know to find the point spectrum $\sigma_p$, we have to solve
$$
(A-\lambda \mathbb{I})x = 0
$$
to find the points where $A-\lambda \mathbb{I}$ is not injective. How to find the points of $\sigma_c$ and $\sigma_r$?
I know that these are both cases for $\lambda$ where $A-\lambda \mathbb{I}$ is not surjective but not how to find these.

Comment: In your example the point spectrum consists of $1/n+4i/n^2.$ The continuous spectrum is just one point $0.$ There is no residual spectrum, as the operator is normal.

Comment: How did you find that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator is of the form $$Ax=\{a_nx_n\}_{n=1}^\infty,\qquad a_n\neq 0,\ a_n\to 0$$
Let $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty $ denote the standard basis in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N}).$ Then $Ae_n=a_ne_n.$ Hence
$$\{a_n\,:\, n\in \mathbb{N}\}\subset \sigma_p(A)$$
The operator $A$ is injective and
$${\rm Im}\,A=\{y\in \ell^2(\mathbb{N})\,:\, \{y_n/a_n\}\in \ell^2(\mathbb{N})\}\subsetneq \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$$
The space ${\rm Im}\,A$ is dense, as $e_n\in {\rm Im}\,A$ for any $n.$ Hence $0\in\sigma_c(A).$ For $z\notin \{a_n\,:\, n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}$ we have $|z-a_n|\ge \delta$ for a positive number $\delta.$ Then the operator
$$B_zx=\{(a_n-z)^{-1}x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$$ is bounded, namely
$\|B_z\|\le \delta^{-1}$ and $B_z(A-zI)=(A-zI)B_z=I.$ Hence $z\notin\sigma(A).$